# Which preposition do I use with a URL?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of the following is correct:

1. You will find more information on [URL]
2. You will find more information at [URL]

I have tried googling, using various actual URLs, but I'm not getting any useful results... Googling has helped me decide that "on" is preferred together with "website", but I'm not sure this automatically holds for actual URLs as well.

Comment: A URL is an address. You live _at_ an address: not _on_ one. Information may be _on_ a website though, like a tent on a campsite.

Comment: Note that the choice of **a** or **an** before a word or letter does NOT depend on the word/letter, but on its pronunciation. So, if URL were pronounced as EARL, it would be preceded by **an**. But because we pronounce the **U**,  as in **uniform**, not as in **umbrella**, it is **a URL** and NOT **an URL**.

Comment: @RonaldSole You're right, of course – my mistake!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The abbreviation “URL” is new enough that I doubt a rigid usage has developed.

However, I’d recommend “at.”

First, a “URL” is called an address, and usage decrees that the preposition “at” is used for addresses in the physical domain.

Second, email addresses incorporate an “@,” which is a punctuation mark known as a “commercial at.”

Those two analogies suggest strongly that “at” should be used for URL’s.

Comment: URLs usually don't incorporate an "@". Perhaps you're thinking of email addresses?

Comment: You are right. Thank you. My mind slipped a cog there.  I shall correct.